# How to debug instrumentation tests in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, mockito, android-testing, android-espresso

In Android Studio when I debug instrumentation test, the test won't stop on any breakpoint. Debugging unit tests works. I have a simple instrumented test that only checks if username edittext is displayed:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LogonActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LogOnActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(LogOnActivity.class, true, false);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mActivityRule.launchActivity(new Intent()); // breakpoint here
    }

    @Test
    public void testSimple() throws Exception {
        onView(withId(R.id.act_logon_et_username)).check(matches(isDisplayed())); // breakpoint here
    }
}
```

In `build.gradle` I have properly set

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

How can I debug instrumented tests? I'm using Espresso, Mockito and Dagger 2.

Answer (score 12):

You can solve this a couple of ways Tomask.

You can pass the option -e debug true in the configuration for your test if you're invoking the test from the command line.

Otherwise, and more simply, you should choose **Debug** instead of **Run** when starting your tests from android studio. If you click **Run** for your test from android studio, the option -e debug false gets set and the test(s) will not stop execution at breakpoints.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is that although my tests are stoping the execution at the breakpoints, it only stops for few seconds and I'm unable to check what I want.

Answer (score 2):

For me, switching to "Run Android instrumented Tests using Gradle" works fine.

Go to Android Studio -> Preferences and toggle this option.

[image]

If it is already enabled, try disabling it and hope for the best.